# Doctrine2: how do I link entities using two columns (or composite keys)?

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm, multiple-columns, composite-key

I've been trying to find an answer to this question relating to composite from both Doctrine2 documentation and across the internet, but so far have had no firm leads.

To keep it brief, essentially I need to link 3 entities: Object, Grid and GriddingSquare. An object is found in a Grid and, more specifically, within one GriddingSquare. A Grid is composed of 1 or more GriddingSquares.

In the source database (which cannot easily be modified), the GriddingSquare is uniquely identified by 'GridID' (integer) and 'GridSquareLabel' (string). These two columns are thus both in the Object table (& entity) and GriddingSquare table (& entity).

I tried the following, but can't seem to get it work:

Object entity:

```php
/**
 * @var \Grid
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Grid")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="GridID", referencedColumnName="GridID")
 * })
 */
private $gridid;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="GridSquareLabel", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
 */
private $gridsquarelabel;

/**
 * @var \CdbGriddingsquares
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CdbGriddingsquares")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="GridID", referencedColumnName="GridID"),
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="GridSquareLabel", referencedColumnName="GridSquareLabel")
 * })
 */
private $griddingsquare;
```

GriddingSquare entity:

```php
/**
 * @var \Grid
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Grid")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="GridID", referencedColumnName="GridID")
 * })
 */
private $gridid;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="GridSquareLabel", type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $gridsquarelabel;
```

Tried to use the following suggestions from Doctrine2 documentation, but although it is technically a 'composite key' question, I can't seem to find an example which helps me understand what I need to do http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn, and http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html